# Merge iteratively one of multiple columns to dataframes in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a (probably small) issue in iteratively combining columns from a single dataframe with other dataframes from a list. Some data to illustrate:

```r
# load example data
library(vegan)
data(varechem)
data(varespec)

# generate predictor tables with overlapping rows and different amount of cols
varespec1 <- varespec[c(1:9), ]
varespec2 <- varespec[c(8:16), c(1:43)]
varespec3 <- varespec[c(14:24), c(1:41)]

# store predictor tables in list
subset_list <- list(varespec1 = varespec1, 
  varespec2 = varespec2, 
  varespec3 = varespec3)

# generate a table that holds ALL possible response variables as presence/absence
varechem_binary <- as.data.frame(apply(varechem, 2, cut, 
  breaks = c(-Inf, 1.0, Inf), labels = c("Absent", "Present")))
row.names(varechem_binary) <- row.names(varechem)
```

The code above illustrates how I have prepared my data for classification tasks. The idea now is that the `data.frames` containing the predictor variables (`varespec1`, ...) in the list should be used to predict each of the columns in the response table (`varechem_binary`), but **only one at a time**. It is easy to merge the response table with each of the predictor tables:

```r
# merge response table with each predictor table
merge_counter <- 0
merged_list <- list()
for(table in subset_list) {
    merge_counter <- merge_counter + 1
    current_name <- names(subset_list)[merge_counter]
    tmp <- merge(table, varechem_binary, by = "row.names")
    row.names(tmp) <- tmp$Row.names
    tmp <- tmp[, -1]
    merged_list[[current_name]] <- tmp
    rm(tmp)
}
```

Expected output:

What I'm now (or earlier in the code, if that makes more sense) looking for is a way to have a combination of each predictor table with each and exactly one of the columns from response table `varechem` in a list. This would be basically:

```
# storing in data frames just for illustration, I would like to do this within the list
# subsets for the 3 predictor tables with the first response variable
aa <- merged_list[[1]][,-c(46:58)]  # column 1:44 are the predictor variables, then the different response variables start
bb <- merged_list[[2]][,-c(45:57)]  # column 1:43 are the predictor variables, then the different response variables start
cc <- merged_list[[3]][,-c(43:58)] # column 1:41 are the predictor variables, then the different response variables start

# subsets for the 3 predictor tables with the second response variable
dd <- merged_list[[1]][,-c(45, 47:58)]
ee <- merged_list[[2]][,-c(44, 46:57)]
ff <- merged_list[[3]][,-c(42, 44:58)]

# subsets for the 3 predictor tables with the third response variable
gg <- merged_list[[1]][,-c(45, 46, 48:58)]
...

# this is just to illustrate how the list could look like, I would like to keep all files in a list all the time
list_for_classification_runs <- list(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, ...)
```

This resulting list would be the input to a Random Forest classification call where the response variable will be classified by all other predictor variables coming from `varespec` such as:

```r
for (current_table in list_for_classification_runs) {
  counter <- counter + 1 
  # response_variable should be the one variable added to the predictor variables in the data frames 
  RF_list[[counter]] <- ranger(response_variable ~ ., data = current_table)
}
```

Comment: ah sorry, that is just an issue in the example code, in my original data the merged_list works well. I will update the code and explain better what my expected output is

Comment: Storing all of these data frames in lists seems inefficient... seems like you it might be easier to make 1 big data frame with all the responses (or maybe 3 big data frames with all the responses) and give different subsets of data/different formulas to `ranger`

Comment: So, basically using `merged_list[[1]]` and giving ranger `data = merged_list[[1]][, c(1:44, i + 44)`, letting `i` vary from one to the number of responses. And similarly constructing the formula so that the LHS is correct. I just don't see a need to name them all `aa`, `bb`, ... and save them each as separate copies.

Comment: @Gregor: the data frames derive from many different objects, but I could think of ways to combine them. I would have to change the row.names, though, as in my real data they overlap between subsets. The way of iterating through columns looks good if the number of predictor variables are always the same. In my real data they change and I would also like to have them more readable via addressing them by name. I will adjust the example data for this, sorry I didn't even think about this implications

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments of Gregor I came up with a similar approach. I did not merge the full `varechem_binary` with all elements of the `subset_list`, instead I added another for loop and iterated over all the columns in `varechem_binary`. Using `drop = FALSE` the row.names and structure are preserved, so the merge works:

```r
merge_col_counter <- 0
column_counter <- 0
merged_column_list <- list()

for(table in subset_list) {
    merge_col_counter <- merge_col_counter + 1
    for (column in names(varechem_binary)) {
      column_counter <- column_counter + 1
      current_name <- paste(names(subset_list)[merge_col_counter], names(varechem_binary)[column_counter], sep = "_")
      print(current_name)
      tmp <- merge(table, varechem_binary[, column_counter, drop = FALSE], by = "row.names")
      row.names(tmp) <- tmp$Row.names
      tmp <- tmp[, -1]
      merged_column_list[[current_name]] <- tmp
      rm(tmp)
    }
    column_counter <- 0
}
```

There are probably ways to do this cleaner or more efficient, but it works, so I can continue

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using apply functions:

```
lapply(subset_list, function(x) apply(varechem_binary, 2, function(var) merge(var, x, by= 'row.names')))
```

Using system.time() to benchmark these two approaches using your sample data, this approach is twice as fast (0.075 user  time) as your solution using the for loop (0.143 user time).